# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, mongodb, react-native

I get this error whenever I use the api and send post, `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

[image]

**This is the code !**

```
//LOGIN
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
      !user && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");
  
      const validated = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
      !validated && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");
  
      const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
      res.status(200).json(others);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  });



module.exports = router;
```

I don't know why I get this error, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works:

```js
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
      if(!user) return res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");
  
      const validated = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
      if(!validated) return res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");
  
      const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
      return res.status(200).json(others);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  });



module.exports = router;
```

Added returns, so that once a `res.json()` completes, it ensures the next one doesn't run.

Comment: it worked, thank you friend you're a lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

- The keyword `return` prevents the `execution` of your code. That means that any lines of code after it will not be executed.

```js
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
      if(!user){
       return res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");
      }
  
      const validated = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
      if(!validated){
        return res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");
      }
  
      const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
      return res.status(200).json(others);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  });
```